# How can I map a list of strings to my entity using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I've got two tables in my database: Articles and Tags

The Tags tables consist of ArticleID (foreign key) and a Tag (varchar).

Now I need to map an articles tags into a readonly collection on Article entity, either using IList Tags or ReadOnlyCollection Tags.

I've consulted the NHibernate reference material, but I can't seem to figure when to use Set, Bag and the other Nhibernate collections. I've seen examples using the ISet collection, but I really don't like to tie my entity classes to a NHibernate type.

How can I do the mapping in NHibernate?

edit: I ended up using a `<bag>` instead, as it doesn't require an index:

```
<bag name="Tags" table="Tag" access="nosetter.camelcase" lazy="false">
  <key column="ArticleId" />
  <element column="Tag" type="System.String" />
</bag>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of collection to use in your mapping depends on how you want to represent the collection in code. The settings map like so:

- The `<list>` maps directly to an
  IList.
- The `<map>` maps directly to an IDictionary.
- The `<bag>` maps to an IList. A  does not completely comply
  with the IList interface because the
  Add() method is not guaranteed to
  return the correct index. An object
  can be added to a `<bag>` without
  initializing the IList. Make sure to
  either hide the IList from the
  consumers of your API or make it
  well documented.
- The `<set>` maps to an Iesi.Collections.ISet. That
  interface is part of the
  Iesi.Collections assembly
  distributed with NHibernate.

so if you want an IList to be returned, then you would use the `<list>` mapping. In your case, I'd probably map using the `<list>` mapping.